# Polygon corners from a numpy array or arrays

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy arary of numpy arrays of (x,y) points that make up a filled polygon.

```
[[ 441  455]
 [ 442  455]
 [ 443  455]
 ...
 [1737 1444]
 [1738 1444]
 [1739 1444]]
```

I need to find the corners of this polygon. How would one go about this?

---

Context:
I'm using detectron2 for instance segmentation, and I received back a tensr of prediction masks, showing whether each pixel is representing the object or not. After some manipulation with numpy, I transformed this into a numpy array of numpy arrays representing all coordinates that are representing the polygon.

```
outputs = predictor(im)
outputnump = outputs["instances"].pred_masks.numpy()
ind1 = np.nonzero(outputnump[0])
ind = np.insert(ind1[0],np.arange(len(ind1[0])),ind1[1])
#ind = np.flip(ind,[1])
ind_len_div2 = int(len(ind)/2)
ind = ind.reshape(ind_len_div2,2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep the mask array and use the Marching Cube algorithm to describe the polygon, after that you may use an algorithm that simplifies the polygon.

```py
from skimage.measure import find_contours, approximate_polygon

# mask should be your output mask
contours = find_contours(mask)
simple_contours = [approximate_polygon(p, tolerance=2) for p in contours]
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer given by Gabriel works fine & tandy, I've decided to opt for another route, given that I feel much more comfortable with opencv than skimage.

```
  def random_colour_masks(image):
        colours = [[0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255], [255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 255], [255, 255, 0], [255, 0, 255],
                           [80, 70, 180], [250, 80, 190], [245, 145, 50], [70, 150, 250], [50, 190, 190]]
        r = np.zeros_like(image).astype(np.uint8)
        g = np.zeros_like(image).astype(np.uint8)
        b = np.zeros_like(image).astype(np.uint8)
        image == 1], g[image == 1], b[image == 1] = colours[random.randrange(0, 10)]
        coloured_mask = np.stack([r, g, b], axis=2)
        return coloured_mask




masks = outputs['instances'].pred_masks.numpy()#[::-1, :]                       
rgb_mask = random_colour_masks(masks[0]) 
gray_mask = cv.cvtColor(rgb_mask, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)                                         
# Find contours:                         

contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(gray_mask, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) 
polycorners = cv.approxPolyDP(contours[0], 0.00065 * cv.arcLength(contours[0], False), False)
```